# Trying to experiment with some Resharper Open APIs

Tags: resharper

I was trying to read a C# source file and parse it using Resharper. I wanted to get the list of namespaces used in the file but I had an exception in this line.

```
   ICSharpFile file = CSharpParserUtil.Parse(sCode);
```

**Exception Details:**
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in 
JetBrains.Platform.ReSharper.Shell.dll

The thread 0x1020 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x14c0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).

```
  static void Main()
    {

        String sCode = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\ResharperTries\TestFile.cs");

        try
        {
            ICSharpFile file = CSharpParserUtil.Parse(sCode);
            IList<ICSharpNamespaceDeclaration> x = file.NamespaceDeclarations;

            foreach (ICSharpNamespaceDeclaration value in x)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(value.ContainingNamespace.ShortName);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Need some help regarding this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to do this with the parsers that are part of DXCore and CodeRush.

In version 10.2 we released **stand-alone parser libraries** for C# and VB (part of the **freely downloadable** DXCore), so referencing the parser libraries will make it very easy to do what you’re looking for.

If you need help with this, simply email support@devexpress.com with any questions.

Here is sample of code, which can be used to fill ListBox with namespaces, used in some file:

```
 string filePath = @"InsertFilePathHere";
 CSharp30Parser parser = new CSharp30Parser();

 SourceFile fileNode = parser.ParseFile(filePath) as SourceFile;
 if (fileNode == null || fileNode.UsingList == null)
   return;
 lbUsedNamespaces.Items.Clear();
 for (int i = 0; i < fileNode.UsingList.Count; i++)
 {
   string strUsing = fileNode.UsingList.GetKey(i) as String;
   if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(strUsing))
     continue;
   lbUsedNamespaces.Items.Add(strUsing);
 }
```

Comment: Thank You Alex and Rory for the reply... Resharper is already used in my team and we wanted to have some add-ons to it, so we wanted a workaround in Reshaper itself...Is it possible to use DXCore libraries with resharper (Without using CodeRush) in such situations?

Comment: Indeed the DXCore is available separately from DevExpress @ http://DevExpress.com/dxcore Additionally CodeRush and CodeRush Xpress (Free Version sponsored by Microsoft) should play nice with our competitors. If you encounter problems then please feel free to contact support, who will assist you in any way they can.

Comment: Thank you Rory, this is really a good piece of information for me...I will try to use DXCore in my project.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, it's impossible to use ReSharper API without Visual Stdio as in your example with console app.
You need to write R# plugin and it will be loaded into R# in Visual Studio.

Take a look at http://resharperpowertoys.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks Derigel..I am using Visual Studio as an editor but I want to get the basic understanding of how R# Open APIs work by parsing a simple C# file..Can we use some services or any other method to use R# without creating a plugin? As the easiest way for me to understand the inbuilt functions is by printing it in the console..If not can you please suggest me some alternative ways for testing in such simple manner.

Comment: Nope, currently almost no services available without VS.
In R#6 we are planning release some test framework that we are using for unit testing. It contains mock objects to emulate VS environment.